# Synchronized, lock and wait blocking main UI thread

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, synchronized

I have made a simple `TaskManager` trying to manage a `Runnable` queue that is needed for my project. However, with a simple scenario, adding a new `Runnable` blocks the calling thread (main UI thread).

It happens when you add a new task while a current task is not finished. 
You can find below a scenario that reproduces it.
I don't clearly understand why, and how I could prevent this.

This is the task manager class :

```
public class TaskManager {

    private Queue<Runnable> executionQueue;
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    public TaskManager() {
        executionQueue = new LinkedList<>();
        startListening();
    }

    public void executeAsyncWithCompl(Runnable runnable, CompletionHandler completionHandler) {
        Runnable runnableWithCompl = new RunnableWithCompl(runnable, completionHandler);
        executeRunnable(runnableWithCompl);
    }

    private void executeRunnable(Runnable runnable) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            executionQueue.add(runnable);
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public void release() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            lock.notify();
        }
    }

    private void startListening() {
        Thread executionThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                listenTasks();
            }
        });
        executionThread.start();
    }

    private void listenTasks() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    if(executionQueue.isEmpty()) {
                        lock.wait();
                    }
                    Runnable runnable = executionQueue.poll();
                    runnable.run();
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    ie.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the RunnableWithCompl class :

```
public class RunnableWithCompl implements Runnable {

    private CompletionHandler completionHandler;
    private Runnable runnable;

    public RunnableWithCompl(Runnable runnable, CompletionHandler completionHandler) {
        this.runnable = runnable;
        this.completionHandler = completionHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        runnable.run();
        if(completionHandler != null)
            completionHandler.onFinish();
    }
}
```

And the CompletionHandler interface :

```
public interface CompletionHandler {
    void onFinish();
}
```

The scenario. Let's say you have an Activity with a spinner (to show UI is not blocked), and a button to trigger long tasks.

```
private TaskManager taskManager;

public void init() {
    taskManager = new TaskManager();
    launchLongTask();
}

private void onButtonClick() {
      launchLongTask() ;
}

private void launchLongTask() {
    Runnable longTask = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(15000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        Log.d(TAG, "Launching long task");

        taskManager.executeAsyncWithCompl(longTask, new CompletionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Long task finished");
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are reinventing the wheel of the executor classes in `java.util.concurrent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `startListening()` implementation. 
It holds the monitor to `lock` while it is executing tasks which means no other method can obtain the monitor while it is doing work. 
This means `release()` and `executeRunnable(...)` will block until there are no more runnables queued.

It also means the thread might block if the thread running `startListening()` is notified before other threads, because it means those threads cannot continue until it releases the monitor.

Comment: Thank you, I think you solved my issue ! If I move the synchronized block (in listenTasks) just around the if(executionQueue.isEmpty(), to avoid keeping the monitor while the task is running, then it works ! Is it a good solution ? Thank you again

Comment: @Xys Yes, although you should check if `runnable` is null afterwards, if something calls `release()` without first putting something into the queue it'd return nothing.